# STL algorithm copy if with functor

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

Which algorithm or combine of algorithms can use for following situation?

```
struct Term
{
    int ix;
    double f;
};

std::vector<Term> terms = <intitalize terms>;
std::vector< int > termIxVector;

// NEED get all `ix` from the `terms` where term.f < 1.0, 
   // and insert 'ix' result to termIxVector.
//i.e. equavalent this loop:
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < terms.size(); ++i)
    if ( terms[i].f < 1.0 )
             termIxVector.push_back(terms[i].ix);
```

std::copy_if  copies only Term structure.  std::transform - doesn't support predicate.

Comment: A plain (range-based) for loop should be plenty enough. Or `std::for_each` if you really want an `<algorithm>`. Does that not suit you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::for_each` with a lambda

```
std::for_each(terms.begin(), terms.end(), 
              [&termIxVector](Term const& t) { 
                  if(t.f < 1.0) termIxVector.push_back(t.ix); 
              });
```

Or a range based `for`

```
for(auto const& t : terms) {
  if(t.f < 1.0) termIxVector.push_back(t.ix);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm use Visual Studio 2010 which doesn't support lambda with capture (simple lambda can), and range based 'for' also can't support. Couldn't You show without lambda and range-base 'for' way ?
I'm more interesting combination of algorithms.

Comment: VS2010 supports lambda with capture, we use them all the time.

Comment: @Khurshid What error are you getting from VS2010? I don't have it installed anymore, but I seem to remember lambdas that capture variables working just fine on it. What if you don't explicitly name the variable you're capturing? `[&](Term const& t) { ... }`

Comment: @Praetorian: VS2010 - support lambda capture by reference only, explicit capture by value doens't -- in common VS2010 100% not support C++11 lambda.

Comment: @Khurshid I have no idea what you're going on about. I am capturing the vector by reference, not by value. And, once again, I'm pretty sure VS2010 supports both. If I remember correctly, the only thing it doesn't support is implicit conversion of a capture-less lambda to a function pointer. Try the code, and post any errors you see. And there is no other *interesting combinations* of algorithms to be used here. You only need the one - `for_each`. If you don't *want to use* a lambda, you can create a functor by hand, but it's essentially the same as the lambda.

Comment: @Praetorian. Thanks. I googled some transform_if algorithm, but not found.

Comment: @Praetorian +1 because it works, but Boost.Range ftw, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of compositions of elementary algorithms are most conveniently done with [**Boost.Range**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html):

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct Term
{
    int ix;
    double f;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    auto terms = std::vector<Term>{ {0, 0.1}, {1, 1.1}, {2, 0.8}, {3, 1.2}, {4, 0.9} };
    auto termIxVector = terms 
        | filtered([](auto const& x){ return x.f < 1.0; }) // select
        | transformed([](auto const& y){ return y.ix; })   // project
    ;    

    boost::copy(termIxVector, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));    
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d746f8b85c34fabc) using Clang 3.5 SVN which prints the indices 0, 2, and 4 of your `Term` elements having a `double` less than 1.0.

**NOTE**: these ranges are lazily computed, and `termIxVector` is not a `std::vector<int>` actually. If you want that, you need to do something like

```
std::vector<int> termIxVector;
boost::push_back(termIxVector, /* RHS of the same range composition as above */);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `std::copy_if`, then an idea is to overload `operator int()` in the struct and use the standard `std::copy_if` with a unary predicate (lambda or functor), as this will allow you to convert `Term` to `int`. Code below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct Term{
    int ix;
    double f;
    operator int(){
        return ix;
    }
};

struct predicate{ // if you don't want a lambda
    bool operator()(const Term& t){
        return (t.f < 1.0 ? true : false);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Term> terms = {{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 1.1}, {4, 0.9}};
    std::vector< int > termIxVector;

    std::copy_if(terms.begin(), terms.end(), 
                 back_inserter(termIxVector), predicate());

    for(auto& elem: termIxVector)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```